# Java docs that include classes based on inheritance

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, doclet

Note that I have written "Java docs", as I'm not necessarily expecting the javadoc utility to acheive what I'm after (let alone the maven-javadoc-plugin I'm using).

I need to produce a doc site that includes only classes that extends/implements a particular interface and, unfortunately, such classes don't seem to be arranged in a logical package structure that allows me to do this by filtering on package path.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own custom Doclet that extends the [standard doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html) but only generates the classes you require. See the docs on [using alternate doclets with the maven javadoc plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html).